# Unity parameter constructor exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

Within the bootstrapper class of my WebApi I'm trying to register a new instance of a class called 'Facade' based on its interface type.

Within this type being regitered it requires a new instance of 'CRUDOperator' which also has a new instance of 'Adaptor' in its constructor. Is what I'm trying to do possible? I am currently just recieving an exception that the overload params are incorrect.

```
 public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        *****ERROR*****
        container.RegisterType<IFacade,Facade>(new CRUDOperatorSelector(new Adapter()));

        return container;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity is capable of resolving concrete types without registering them, so if in Your case the types CRUDOperatorSelector and Adapter are concrete types (and I'm assuming they are) you just have to register the type Facade as implementation of IFacade and resolve it. Unity will then create an instance of each dependency and pass it to the constructor of Facade.
If some of those types implement an abstraction (an interface or an abstract class) register them also.

Comment: Yes your are correct they're concrete implementations. so it is is as simple as creating a new unity container.....registering the type as shown....container.RegisterType<IFacade,Facade>();....and theres no need to try and inject anything into this registered type?

Comment: Yes it should be that simple ;) The extra question is what kind of lifetime do You need for these types - by default You get a new instance of those types everytime when unity will need to resolve them - for instance if there are other types accepting CRUDOperatorSelector and Adapter in their constructor each of them will get a separate new instance - I hope You know what I mean here ;)

Comment: @Prezemek Walendowski. Thanks! That was it, looks like I was going wayyy to indepth! Can you answer the question please so I can select your answer as correct.

Comment: What do You mean by answer the question? ;) Edit the previous one and add the line of code with registration? ;) I'm confused a little here :P

Comment: All sorted now. Still not sure why someone down voted me. But thanks for your answer